# ffmpeg wrong ：100 buffers queued in out_0_1, something may be wrong

Tags: ffmpeg

I wanted to merge three videos using ffmPEG, using the filter, but at the end of the output, there was a warning message: （ 100 buffers queued in out_0_1, something may be wrong）

I use the command line

```
ffmpeg -i r3.mp4 -i r2.mp4 -i logo.jpg -i r1.mp4 -r 24 -filter_complex "[3:v]scale=720:-2,fifo[transform];[transform]pad=720:1280:0:(oh-ih)/2:red[pv];[2:v]scale=150:150,fifo[logo];[0:v][logo]overlay=30:40,fifo[pip];[pip][0:a][1:v][1:a][pv][3:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -c:v h264_nvenc -async 1 as.mp4
```

I'm trying to add at the end of the command line

```
 ffmpeg ...(ignore args) -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -c:v h264_nvenc as.mp4
```

But the warning is still there, I'm new, I don't know how to handle it